# What is the syntax for calling a static typed method while doing a import static?

Tags: java, syntax, static, static-import

Currently I am doing

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
...
foo.bar(EasyMock.<List<String>>anyObject());
```

I wonder if there is a way to avoid mentioning the class `EasyMock`. I have something like this in mind:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.anyObject;
...
foo.bar(anyObject<List<String>>());
```

which, however, does not compile. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Hmm ... that ought to work.  What are the compilation errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to provide type-arguments to statically imported methods (without including the class name as you do in your first snippet). There's simply no such syntax supporting it.

See [Section 15.12, Method Invocation Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12) in the Java Language Specification:

```
MethodInvocation:
        MethodName ( ArgumentListopt )
        Primary . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier (ArgumentListopt)
        super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier (ArgumentListopt)
        ClassName . super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier (ArgumentListopt)
        TypeName . NonWildTypeArguments Identifier (ArgumentListopt)
```

The first option is the only one that does not involve a preceding dot, and that one does not include the possibility to provide type arguments (as the other ones do).

Answer (score 1):

There's no such a syntax. What you can do though is to assign a value to some variable so that  java would infer the type for you. Unfortunately, it won't give you more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.anyObject;
...
foo.bar((List<String>) anyObject());
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be improved to `foo.bar((<List<String>>) anyObject());`, as per the original post?

Comment: That's not the same as explicitly providing type arguments, right? What if `anyObject` returns `void` for instance?

Comment: @aioobe, not indeed, but at least in this specific case it works. And as you pointed out, there is no general solution.

Comment: How can you say it works in this specific case? What if `bar` takes a `String` as argument?

Comment: I do not know that it does, but your post is typed differently than the original post `List<String>` rather than `<List<String>>`, thus my question, rather than my assertion that it should be changed.

Comment: @aioobe, I presume that if the first example above (`foo.bar(EasyMock.<List<String>>anyObject())`) compiled and ran fine, `foo.bar` does take a `List<String>` argument.

Comment: Then you're either interpreting `<List<String>>` as an attempt to cast the result of `anyObject` to `List<String>` (even though he talks about providing type arguments) or that `anyObject` is declared as something like `public static <T> T anyObject`, (i.e. that `anyObject` returns something of the same type as the type argument. What if `bar` takes a `String` as argument and `anyObject` always returns a `String`?

Comment: @Zéychin, yes, in theory it would be nicer, but I checked and it does not compile.

Comment: @PéterTörök: Ah. Alright then. It was worth a shot, for continuity's sake! Thanks for checking!

Comment: @aioobe, yes, the signature is `public static <T> T anyObject()`, so I don't see the point of your *what if*. As I stated, my solution is a workaround for this specific case. It isn't the best and nicest, but it works.